# Debug jsfl in ExtendScript for Flash CS5

Tags: flash-cs5, jsfl, extendscript

This is a total noob question, but I'm trying to figure out how I can debug some JSFL that I created, stepping through it as the code runs on a Flash CS5 file.  The DEBUG menu dropdown in ExtendScript has "run" grayed out...

If I double click the file, it runs in Flash and the output shows in the Output tab.  But I want to step through my code in debug mode and watch the values of variables as it executes against the currently open Flash file.

Is this possible?  Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is that I am unable to target Flash CS5.5 in the "Connect to target application" dropdown.  Flash is not appearing as an option in the dropdown list.  hmmmmm, how do I go about adding it?

Comment: connect to target application looks specifically for the flash debug player and wouldn't apply to the jsfl. @Mike, fl.trace is really cumbersome and annoying. i would also like to know if there is a way to debug jsfl using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

If u wanna edit JSFL file by Flash, u need open it by File > Open, not by dbl click.
For "debuging" i suggest to use fl.trace("some text in quotes " + orScriptVars)